# Moving a factor variable up one row relative to another

Tags: r, data-cleaning

Not really sure how to figure out this out.

Here is a sample data set:

```
 Bob <- sample("Bob", 6, replace = T)
Jeff <- sample("Jeff", 6, replace = T)
Carl <- sample("Carl", 6, replace = T)
Name <- array(c(Bob, Jeff, Carl), dim = c(18,1))
Week <- c("Week 1", "Week 2", "Week 3", "Week 4", "Week 5", "Week 6",
        "Week 1", "Week 2", "Week 3", "Week 4", "Week 5", "Week 6",
        "Week 1", "Week 2", "Week 3", "Week 4", "Week 5", "Week 6")

variable.1 <- c("No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No",
            "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No",
            "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes")

df <- data.frame(Name, Week, variable.1)
df

   Name   Week variable.1
1   Bob Week 1         No
2   Bob Week 2         No
3   Bob Week 3         No
4   Bob Week 4        Yes
5   Bob Week 5         No
6   Bob Week 6         No
7  Jeff Week 1        Yes
8  Jeff Week 2         No
9  Jeff Week 3         No
10 Jeff Week 4         No
11 Jeff Week 5        Yes
12 Jeff Week 6         No
13 Carl Week 1         No
14 Carl Week 2        Yes
15 Carl Week 3         No
16 Carl Week 4         No
17 Carl Week 5         No
18 Carl Week 6        Yes
```

What I am trying to do is move any "Yes" in the variable.1 column up a row so that it can be reflected as a factor variable for the information in the week prior. I'm trying to do this by the individual (not the data set as a whole). I can't figure out the best way of going about this when both variables are factors. Ideally, I'd like an NA to appear. I don't want everything to simply move up. I just want an NA to appear in the place the "Yes" was and have it override the "No" above it.

So, I'd ideally like the finished product to loo like "New.Col" below:

```
   Name   Week variable.1 New.Col
1   Bob Week 1         No      No
2   Bob Week 2         No      No
3   Bob Week 3         No     Yes
4   Bob Week 4        Yes      NA
5   Bob Week 5         No      No
6   Bob Week 6         No      No
7  Jeff Week 1        Yes      NA
8  Jeff Week 2         No      No
9  Jeff Week 3         No      No
10 Jeff Week 4         No     Yes
11 Jeff Week 5        Yes      NA
12 Jeff Week 6         No      No
13 Carl Week 1         No     Yes
14 Carl Week 2        Yes      NA
15 Carl Week 3         No      No
16 Carl Week 4         No      No
17 Carl Week 5         No     Yes
18 Carl Week 6        Yes      NA
```

Comment: What do you want to happen for situations like (Jeff, Week 1, Yes)?

Comment: Ah, good question. Sorry for not saying. Will update my post. Ideally, I'd like an NA to appear. I don't want everything to simply move up. I just want an NA to appear in the place the "Yes" was and have it override the "No" above it.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. Could you give what you'd like the new column for this example to be?

Comment: Sorry, it is tough for me to really explain it. I put in an example in my original post of what I'd like it to look like.

Comment: It's fine. Now we that both have a better idea of the question, it becomes easier to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this.

I'm going to go ahead and sort `df` by Name and Week just in case some of the data got out of order. (This won't account to any missing weeks!) I'll also make a copy of `variable.1` as characters in `newcol` to play with.

```
df <- df[order(df$Name, df$Week),]
df$newcol <- as.character(df$variable.1)
```

For ease of understanding, I'll write a loop, but computational, there are better ways to do this.  This loop will look at each unique person in df$Name

```
for (person in unique(df$Name)) {

}
```

Inside the loop, I want to select all entries in `newcol` for each person.

```
oldvalues <- df[df$Name == person, ]$newcol
```

I'll then go ahead and move each value up 1 entry and make the last entry NA.

```
newvalues <- c(oldvalues[2:length(oldvalues)], NA)
```

I also want to account for each time the old value was "Yes" by making that week NA.

```
newvalues[oldvalues == "Yes"] <- NA
```

I can then put it back into `df`.

```
df[df$Name == person,]$newcol <- newvalues
```

Now that the loop is finished, you can make `df$newcol` back into factors either excluding `NA` as a level by default

```
df$newcol <- factor(df$newcol)
```

or making it a third factor level

```
df$newcol <- factor(df$newcol, exclude = NULL)
```

Comment: Thank you. That doesn't seem to work though. If I run that stuff in the for loop I get this Error: Error in `[.data.frame`(df, df$Name == person, df$newcol) :  undefined columns selected

Comment: I apologize. I have two typos which I have fixed.

Comment: Excellent. Than you so much!